# What is the name of this delta operator

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In Euler-Lagrange Equation: $${\delta \over \delta y}F \equiv {\partial F \over \partial y}- {d \over dx} ({\partial F \over \partial {y'}})$$

What is the name of operator $\delta$ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the [functional or variational derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) with respect to $y$.